# If $v$ is in the von Neumann algebra generated by $x$, then $v^*v$ is in the von Neumann algebra generated by $x^*x$.

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M \subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra. Given $S \subseteq M$, let $VNA(S)$ be the von Neumann algebra generated by $S$. Note that I require von Neumann algebras to be unital, so $VNA(S) = S''$ (I think).

If $v \in VNA(x)$ where $x \in M$, do we also have $v^*v \in VNA(x^*x)$?

Attempt: $v$ is a ultraweak limit of polynomials in $x$ and $x^*$, but I can't conclude from this that $v^*v$ is a limit of polynomials in $x^*x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The von Neumann algebra generated by a set is $(S\cup S^*)''$.

Anyway, the answer to your question is no. Take $M=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \qquad v=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} .
$$
Then $v\in W^*(x)$. In fact, $v\in\operatorname{span}\{x\}$, since $v=I+x$. But $x^*x=1$, so $W^*(x^*x)=\mathbb C\,1$, while $v^*v=2v$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a follow-up if you have time/interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095808/question-about-polar-decomposition-inside-a-von-neumann-algebra