# Question about polar decomposition inside a von Neumann algebra.

Tags: operator-theory, polar-coordinates, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M \subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra.

Let $x = v|x|$ be the polar decomposition of $x$. It is well-known that $v,|x| \in M$. Is it true that the element $v^*v$ is an element of the von Neumann algebra generated by $x^*x$?

Attempt: Maybe it is useful to look at the polar decomposition of $x^*x$. We also know that $v^*v$ is the projection on $ker(x)^\perp$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because $v^*v$ is the projection onto the closure of the range of $x^*x$ (as this is equal to the closure of the range of $x^*$). Von Neumann algebras contain range projections.

Comment: I didn't know that von Neumann algebras contain range projections! This is a very useful result. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It's a basic of Borel functional calculus. Your algebra contains $1_{\sigma(x^*x)}(x^*x)$, which is the range projection.

Comment: I think you also get the range projection if you do $\lim_n(x^*x)^{1/n}$.